# ArcGIS Online spatial analysis

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, spatial-analysis

I am currently attempting to put together a web mapping application for a client through the AGOL web app builder.  One of the layers in the application is a set of grid cells covering a large geographic area.  Another layer is a set of points containing a scoring value.  The client would like to be able to summarize the points that fall into each grid cell and symbolize the grid cells based on the aggregated point score for each cell.

I am aware there are tools in AGOL that can perform spatial analysis, but every time the analysis is run new data is created.  I would like a solution that updates and symbolizes the grid cells as the underlying point data changes.  Has anyone attempted something like this or had any luck with something similar?